# Multiple domains and SSL Certificates with GCP's kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am exposing a micro service running on GCP's kubernetes engine via Google's Ingress load balancer. According to [Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl) the load balancer supports multiple SSL certificates for different domain namess.

However, only the first specified SSL certificate is returned and therefore I receive a `Your connection is not private` warning for a domain-b. I would love to make an ingress controller for several domains each with their own certificate.

The following approach fails:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-name
spec:  
  tls:
  - hosts: 
    - www.domain-a.net
    - domain-a
    secretName: domain-a-net
  - hosts: 
    - www.domain-b.org
    - domain-b.org
    secretName: domain-b-org
  backend:
    serviceName: some-name
    servicePort: 443
```

Any idea how to correctly benefit from Google's Ingress Multi SSL?

Comment: Hopefully this will help you. It's almost one year old but I think it remains current: https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-10-domain-ingress-c6c2bbf381bb

Comment: Can you run `curl -k -v` on these hostnames and see which domain returns which cert –and add that to the question? The feature is supposed to work as documented.

Comment: Hi @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google I just ran `curl -k -v` for both domains. I always get the secret for domain-a returned. After some testing, I have the feeling that I always get the first specified secretName in my return (domain-a-net) i.e. if I would switch the two hosts in aboves YAML file I would receive domain-b-org as a result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RobertWeindl please try that out, and if that's the case, I'll have it investigated. Also feel free to report this on https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/ if you have reliable repo. This is critical.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google Thanks for your feedback and help. I verified that behavior and opened https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating GCE and GKE to latest version, and then redeploying the Ingress resource helped!